# How do I cast InternalLinkedHashMap as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, firebase-cloud-messaging, linkedhashmap

Im setting up firebase cloud messaging and in my `onResume()` callback I have the following:

```
Future<void> onResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      final Map<String,dynamic> data = message['data'];
      final String url = data['url'];
      if (url != null) {
        _webViewController?.loadUrl(url);
      }
  }
```

When the function reaches
`final Map<String,dynamic> data = message['data'];`
it returns prematurely and silently without warnings.

If I instead run
`final dynamic data = message['data'];`
it continues as expected.

Inspecting the `message` type revels that `message` is `InternalLinkedHashMap` and cannot be cast too `Map<String, dynamic>`.

It says `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`.

How do I do this?
How can I find this issue in the future if it has no trace?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the best way to solve it were to use Map.from() and specify the variable type as Map:

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map.from(message['data']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, I wasted hrs. to get this answer. Can you please also suggest how to get list

Comment: To cast a List<dynamic> to List<int> using the above syntax you would type  
   `final List<dynamic> dynamicList = [];`  
   `final List<int> intList = List.from(dynamicList);`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
final Map<String,dynamic> data = Map.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic>(message['data']);
```

You should only do this, of course, if all of your keys are really Strings.

If you want to understand what's going on, see this:

```
var x = {};
print(x.runtimeType);
Map<String, dynamic> y = Map.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic>(x);
print(y.runtimeType);
```

Comment: I get why `String` might be a problem, but why is `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` an issue?
Shouldn't any `HashMap` be able to be converted to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`?

Comment: But you are doing the opposite. You are not converting "to", but "from" `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. You are taking a map where keys are `dynamic`, and you are trying to put its content into a map that only accepts `String` keys. Got it?

Comment: In the example above, yes.
But if I change data to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` then I'm trying to cast  message (`Map<String, dynamic>`) to a new variable data(`Map<dynamic, dynamic>`). I feel like ´String´ could be cast to ´dynamic´?

Comment: The opposite works. This works: `Map<String, dynamic> x = {"a": 10, "b": true}; Map<dynamic, dynamic> y = x;` If you have some code that doesn't work, show me.

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to convey with my previous comment. If you take my code and replace the data type to Map<dynamic, dynamic> it still fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to map all keys to string. Something like:

```
final Map<String,dynamic> data = message.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key.toString(), value));
```